# How to set time interval in between queries?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Need to give time inerval as 5 seconds in between queries. To know the table is in update state trying to get count of rows two times withn interval of 5 seconds.
How to set time inerval in between queries?

Comment: Can you rephrase this more intelligibly?

Answer (score 2):

Don't really understand all your question text but

```
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'
```

Will give you a 5 second delay